# Delete slash before custom permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress and it's plugin Custom Permalink. There is a place in this plugin, where added / before custom permalink and i want to delete it, because it make final link such as href="http://domain.com//post-title". 
Please help me find a place, where added this second /. Any help, please!

PROBLEM disappears, when turn off WPML plugin

Comment: I can paste the code of plugin, but its rather big, and i don't understand, how can i post it here

Comment: in your plugin check for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and paste all code of after that

Comment: $request = ltrim(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($url)),'/');
 $request = (($pos=strpos($request, '?')) ? substr($request, 0, $pos) : $request);
 $request_noslash = preg_replace('@/+@','/', trim($request, '/'));

Answer (score 0):

You can regex for it:

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('/(\/+)/','/',$url);
```